# how can i install ubuntu from one computer to other one? (in my computer there is no internet connection)

Tags: installation

Its very important because my pc uses windows xp and i want to get ubuntu (latest version).
I have tried installing it rom my computer, but for having wifi i must log in as the adminitrator, but i cant remember the password

Comment: create a bootable usb and install as usual. you don't need an internet connection to install Ubuntu..

Answer (score 0):

Official "Creating a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from Windows" howto is here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_a_bootable_Ubuntu_USB_flash_drive_from_Windows